# Dynamic DNS updates for Linux and Mac OS X machines with a Windows DNS server

Tags: domain-name-system, domain, dhcp, dynamic-dns

My network has a Windows machine running Server 2008 R2 which provides DHCP and DNS. I'm not particularly familiar with Windows domains, but the domain is set to `home.local` and that is the DNS domain name provided with DHCP leases.

Everything works fine for Windows machines, they get the lease and update the server with their hostname and the server creates a DNS records for `windowshostname.home.local`.

I am having problems obtaining the same functionality on Linux (Debian) and Mac OS X (Mountain Lion) machines. They receive DHCP just fine, but DNS entries are not being created on the server for them.

On the Mac OS X machine, `hostname` gives an output of `machostname.local`, and on the Linux machine `hostname --fqdn` also gives an output of `linuxhostname.local`. I'm assuming that the server is not creating DNS entries because the domain does not match that of the server (`home.local`).

I don't want to statically configure these machines to be part of the `home.local` domain, I just want them to pick it up from DHCP and be able to have entries in the DNS server. How should I go about doing this?

Comment: Which version of OS X? Which Linux distribution(eg: Debian, Ububtu ..)?

Comment: Is the server a Domain Controller and are the machines that work joined to that domain? How are you updating the records, using secure self-registered updates, or DHCP DNS update delegation?

Comment: @JohnSiu That information is available in the question.

Comment: @MDMarra Yes it is, most of the working machines are, but there is one Windows machine that is not joined to the domain that still successfully sends a dynamic DNS update to the server. I think it is using DHCP DNS update delegation.

Comment: On a Windows client there can be a primary DNS suffix and/or a connection specific DNS suffix. The primary DNS suffix is usually set when a Windows client joins a Windows AD domain (but can be set manually) while the connection specific suffix is set via DHCP (but it too can be set manually). What you're looking at appears to be the primary DNS suffix of the Linux and Mac computers. Can you look at the connection specific DNS suffix for the connection that's getting it's ip address via DHCP?

Comment: Also, if the DNS server is joined to an AD domain then you'll need to allow secure and unsecure updates to the zone.

Comment: @joeqwerty On the Windows machine that is not part of the domain I had to tick the box for "Use this connection's DNS suffix in DNS registration" to make it work so I assume that this means it is the connection specific DNS suffix. And yes I did allow secure and unsecure updates to the zone.

Comment: Yes, that's what I meant. On a Windows machine that's not joined to a domain you need to use the connection specific DNS suffix (assigned from DHCP) so I'm assuming there's something similar for the Mac and Linux computers.

Comment: Yea, that's what I'm trying to find.

Answer (score 0):

I've managed to get it working on the Linux machine using the fix described [here](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/howto-get-linux-static-dhcp-address/): In `/etc/dhcp/dhclient.conf` I added the line

```
send host-name "linuxhostname";
```

Still trying to find a Mac OS X equivalent though.